# How one can set affinity for kernel threads?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, affinity

On a Linux kernel `3.11.0-13-generic` i can't set affinity for kernel threads as in the following example:

```
>ps -p 828
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  828 ?        00:00:00 nfsiod
>sudo taskset -pc 7 828
pid 828's current affinity list: 0-11
taskset: failed to set pid 828's affinity: Invalid argument
>sudo taskset -pc 7 17551
pid 17551's current affinity list: 7
pid 17551's new affinity list: 7
>
```

17551 is a user process, and nfsiod is a kernel thread. How can I change the affinity for the nfsiod deamon running as a kernel thread ?

Comment: Is suppose You look  for "niceness" ???

Comment: `taskset`  isn't programming. Are you looking for a method to do this from inside your code?

Comment: @MSalters no I am looking for doing that on existing kernel threads.

Comment: @MSalters Arrrf, I get your point, I should have posted taht on unix.stackexchange.com, isn't it ? Is there any way to migrate the question over there or should I manually ask it again ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva: I don't think there's a migration path from here to Unix.SE, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many kernel threads set the flag `PF_NO_SETAFFINITY`:

```c
#define PF_NO_SETAFFINITY 0x04000000 /* Userland is not allowed to meddle with cpus_allowed */
```

To change the affinity, you would have to change the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does the boot parameter isolcpus override this restriction ?

Comment: `isolcpus` just adds another restriction.

Comment: what do you mean by it adds another restriction ? Does for example isolcpus=1,2,3 ensures that a kernel thread seting its affinity for example to 0,1,2,3 (on a four core processor, able to run anywhere) will only run on cpu 0 ?

Comment: The `isolcpus` restriction is *independent* from the `PF_NO_SETAFFINITY` check. (And it affects the entire system, so it has no relation to this question.)

Comment: Accepted your answer. Nevertheless I am wondering if the isolcpus parameter will override affinity defined by kernel thread creation code. Do you think I have to ask another question for that ?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out?

Comment: I just tried, and the answer is no. So I conclude that as you suggested the only way to change the affinity for these threads is to change kernel.