# Check value of PF_NO_SETAFFINITY

Tags: affinity, taskaffinity, setthreadaffinitymask, taskset

Is it possible to tell whether a process/thread has the `PF_NO_SETAFFINITY` flag set? I'm running taskset on a series of process ids and some are throwing errors of the following form:

`taskset: failed to set pid 30's affinity: Invalid argument`

I believe this is because some processes have `PF_NO_SETAFFINITY` set (see [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359565/how-one-can-set-affinity-for-kernel-threads)).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - look at  `/proc/PID/stat`'s 'flag' field

```
<linux/sched.h

#define PF_NO_SETAFFINITY 0x04000000        /* Userland is not allowed to meddle with cpus_allowed */
```

Look here for details on using /proc:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html
- https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk65143

Example:

```
ps -eaf
www-data 30084 19962  0 07:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
...

cat /proc/30084/stat
30084 (apache2) S 19962 19962 19962 0 -1 4194624 554 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 298837672 509616128 5510 18446744073709551615 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 16781312 201346799 0 0 0 17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The flags are `4194624`

---

> Q: Do you mind specifying how you'd write a simple script that outputs
>   true/false based on whether you're allowed to set affinity?

A: I *don't* feel comfortable providing this without the opportunity to test, but you can try something like this...

```
flags=$(cut -f 9 -d ' ' /proc/30084/stat)
echo $(($flags & 0x40000000))
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you. Do you mind specifying how you'd write a simple script that outputs true/false based on whether you're allowed to set affinity? I'm not seeing references in any of the docs you linked to PF_NO_SETAFFINITY. Thank you!

Comment: I would if I had a system handy to test it myself.  But, unfortunately, I don't.  Basically "true/false" is just "OR" 0x04000000.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40667440/3135317) for a good example of doing bitwise operations in "bash".

Comment: Ok, perhaps we can wait for someone to edit/post a solution using this info.